# vibration dampening comparison

Tags: pcb, enclosure, vibration, mount

I am trying to mitigate between costs, ease of mounting, of enclosure matching and costs for a smallish PCB (< 100 g / 4 oz and about 35 x 50 mm / 1.5 x 2 in) used inside a passenger car.
And so far I have found these methods:

Snap-in universal anti vibration guides:

[image: Snap-in universal anti vibration guide]

Double sided adhesive tape:

[image]

Adhesive standoffs:

[image]

Vibration dampers:

[image]

Spring washers:

[image]

Staking and potting I think are a bit too much. Any experience with the above methods you could share ?
As a side note, would it hurt not to use any anti-vibration mechanism at all in my scenario ? Largest component would be a button press switch.

Comment: What is the mass of the most fragile part and whole assembly.  Some parts are sensitive to high g short duration others (heavy) to low g, long duration.  As such all HDD's used to have elastomer shock isolation have been eliminated in last 25 years due to reduced mass and risk of resonance as all elastomer isolators (that I have seen &/or  tested) have a gain or Q>5 at resonance.

Comment: Have you done fragility boundary curves yet? g vs v vs t on shock tests!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common industry practise for fragile leaded components is to glob polyurethane adhesive to prevent motion. These come in many grades but sub-floor adhesive works great.!!

PSU makers use the clear , brown or white stuff for ferrite, caps and large relays, magnetic etc.  sorry no vendor p/n on hand.

Comment: PSU makers ? I'll grab a broken old PSU and check it out. Sub-floor adhesive, what's that in plain English ? And those comments - all Chinese to me :D. I am starting to think I can get away without any such protection. For sure most electronics inside the car are not protected, isn't that so ?

Comment: It's comments like this that make some Chinese:) products garbage because they break so easy because some didn't learn the mechanical details of fragility like the TW or Japanese did. So look at how PS parts are globbed to become rigid.  Even some Apple connector/cable designs are garbage and wearout easily. http://www.homedepot.com/p/Loctite-PL-Premium-10-fl-oz-Polyurethane-Construction-Adhesive-1390595/202020473 It does add capacitance, so use where needed to stiffen parts that can vibrate or even USB connectors that stress solder joints from yanked cables and allow few days to harden fully.

Comment: can't beat the cost of this solution

Comment: Just one more thing - about the heat dissipation, I'd like to fully encapsulate three parts in polyurethane adhesive. Any insights ?

Comment: polyurethane, silicone etc are thermal insulators, so that is not wise unless low power dissipation or with thermal conducting leads.

Comment: what do you mean by thermal conductive leads ? Isn't air another good thermal insulator ? I found out on the internet that the thermal conductivity for polyurethane rubber (not adhesive though) is tenfold that of the air. Can I still go this route if I find the thermal conductivity of my product to be around /higher than that of air ?

Comment: moving air by convection or forced air can provide cooling. Blocked air is a good insulator.  What is the temperature rise ( hotspot ) if the unit get if covered with a blanket?  Do you know the power dissipation?

Comment: I see. I do not know the blanket temp rise; I am trying to hold in place 3 bulky power parts that I have left out of the initial design and that are now floating in the casing. So, retrofitting. The parts are a TVS, a forward diode and a resistor all capable of withstanding the 1 kW - ish transients of a passenger car.

Comment: thermal resistance  with convection air is somewhat like Ohms Law for current and voltage rise except Pd * Rja = Temp rise.  Conformal Coating without airflow adds huge thermal resistance (low conductance) that must be considered for hotspots.